# C# ,Why I cannot access a class( Generic parameter) member in inherited class from a interface

Tags: c#

anyone can help me?

I created one interface, using a class as a parameter because I need to save different tables in the SQL database, so I want to create a method to save data to the SQL database.

```
public interface IDataAdapter {        
    void SaveExistingData<T>(T t);
    }
```

and I created another 4 classes, like class BrandAdapter, class ProuductionAdapter, class SupplyAdapter, and OrderAdapter, those 4 classes are all inherited from interface IDataAdapter.

```
public class BrandAdapter : IDataAdapter {       
 public void SaveExistingData<Brand>(Brand updatedBrand) {
        string sql = "UPDATE tblBrands SET " + "brandName=@brandName " +
                     $"WHERE brandID={updatedBrand.brandId}"; //ERROR is at updatedBrand.brandId
        using (var connection = Helper.CreateDatabaseConnection()) {
            connection.Execute(sql, updatedBrand);
        }
    }
```

}

now when I access updatedBrand.brandId, IDE reminder me of an error, I cannot access all members in the Brand class, and "Brand" is a dark yellow color, I can not access its definition by clicking F12, it looks like the system did not recognize it.

if you only create a Brand, it's ok, I can use all members of the Brand class, but When I use generic, it's not ok.
Because I want to use another class as a parameter, so I tried to use generic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you hiding the error from us?

Comment: You have added reference to the project where `Brand` class is created?

Comment: So is this question about interface ?

Comment: if you only create `Brand` not about interface and Generic, is this error still show ?

Comment: @Chetan `Brand` is not a class name, it is a name of type in the declaration of generic method... I suspect that OP wanted something very different from what they wrote in the code, but it is not yet clear what it is (maybe they simply wanted to show shot to write code with SQL injection vulnerability... also I hope it was not the goal).

Comment: Side point: you have SQL injection going on here

Comment: @Charlieface  Do you mean SQL injection is a malicious attack? I should not use this method,   how can I update database data from c# code ?

Comment: Yes, you should have `@"UPDATE tblBrands SET brandName = @brandName WHERE brandID = @brandId"` note *no interpolation*, just use another parameter (although I think you are using Dapper or similar anyway, so that will pass the parameters correctly)

Comment: @Charlieface,  Thanks, yes, its Dapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
public class Brand
{
    public int brandId { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataAdapter<T>
{
    void SaveExistingData(T t);
}

public class BrandAdapter : IDataAdapter<Brand>
{
    public void SaveExistingData(Brand updatedBrand) 
    {
        int abcd = updatedBrand.brandId;
    }
}
```

Comment: My Brand class has propery,        public class Brand {
        public int brandId { get; set; }
        public string brandName { get; set; }     
    }

Comment: you can define any property in Brand if you want .

Comment: public interface IDataAdapter<T>
{
    void SaveExistingData(T t);
}                                       I add <T> follow IDataAdapter,  it resolve my issues,  THANKS Tim.